# Difference between "injunction", "mandate" and "verdict"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Could someone please tell me the difference between *injunction*, *mandate*, and *verdict*? I think they are synonyms, but their usage is different.

I have software for learning English vocabulary, where it's implied that *injunction* means *mandate*. However, from what I have concluded based on different dictionaries, *injunction* is some kind of court order. On the other hand, *mandate* seems to be an official order that someone gives to someone else. For example, voters give a *mandate* to an elected president.

So I think that an *injunction* is always some kind of *mandate*, but a *mandate* is not necessarily some kind of *injunction*. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you clarify how the dictionary definitions are not sufficient?  It looks like you haven't done any research for this question, and unless you edit the question to show research, this question will eventually be closed as "General Reference".

Comment: I did research about this however never came to a conclusion. maybe its because of my lack of understanding of words related to the concept of law.

Comment: Then you should edit the question to clarify your problems based on dictionary definitions, legal articles, or something.  Right now, it looks like you saw those three words, thought "Hmm, those seem like they're the same but I'm not sure", and then posted here.

Comment: I have made some clarification to my question hope it might help.

Comment: Much improved :)

Comment: You realise, of course , that there are also non-legal-domain usages?

Comment: yeah I do. they are used in many different contexts and that even make it harder to distinguish between their usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, an injunction stops somebody from doing something, a mandate requires somebody to do something, and a verdict is the final decision handed down by the bench.

In light of the edit: Black's definition of [mandate](http://thelawdictionary.org/mandate/). Note that a mandate is directed at the official responsible for enforcement, and it's a mandate to enforce the will of the court.

An [injunction](http://thelawdictionary.org/injunction/) is directed at a defendant, and is not a mandate.

Comment: in the link it say : "the mandate is a precept or order issued upon the decision of an appeal or writ of error, directing the action to be taken" So could I roughly say that a mandate is an order to apply an injunction?

Comment: Kind of? An injunction is already an order to apply an injunction, but a mandate could be an order for an injunction to be enforced.